# Can't install Windows 7 service packs with SSD and HDD setup

Tags: windows-7, ssd, service-pack

My computer has consistently failed to install sp1 for many months now, and I finally tried to install it manually.

I got an error 'ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE', I can only assume this is because of my SDD setup.

> 'The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive'

I have hard symlinks (junctions) on my C:/ drive that map to the Program Files directory and everything pretty much except for the System files on my D:/ drive (HDD)

However, SP1 doenst seem to like this. Anyway around this? I havent had much luck finding information from searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using symbolic links, move the folder and change the registry keys as explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542100/changing-program-files-default-location-in-windows-7

On a side note, I wonder why some programs have issues with symbolic links. It is extremely rare but it happens (Windows update in your case and the other one I can think of is the Bitcoin client)

Check the last post of that thread if you have a 64 bit OS - you have one more registry key to change.