# Windows seems to lost part of its configuration, how to fix it?

Tags: windows-7

I had tried to move my "C:/Program Files" to another drive. It failed after about the half because some of the files/programs in "C:/Program files" were opened and couldn't be moved. (I did this in Safe Mode), I moved everything back. Also I tried this with C:/Program Files (x86) by freeing it with Unlocker and then tried to move it.

One of the above steps seems to have destroyed big parts of my windows. Things that changed or problems I discovered so far:

- Every Folder opens in new window when doubleclicked, but not when right-clicked and then "Open"
- Internet Explorer doesn't start
- Windows started to create restoring points (or however they are called in english)
- Some of my plugins like NetSpeedMonitor disappeared.
- Unlocker doesn't appear in context menu anymore.

And so on.
What can be the cause of this and how do I fix it?

I already tried to re-register that proxy dll's that are suggested everywhere.
I already run `sfc /scannow`
I don't have any backup of `C:/` and hence I could not restore.

Comment: In general, you can't just move the "Program Files" folder. There are registry entries that point to places on disk, permissions, and all kinds of other things that application installers magically do to set up a program's install.

Comment: A few of these problems are connected to your actions, have you tried, to use a restore point from before you attempted to migrate the folder?  The problem with opening folders isn't connected to your actions, the behavior is handled by, a windows explorer setting.  You might have to accept the reinstall of Windows is your only solution.

Comment: It isn't moved at the moment. I removed everything after it failed. I tried to setup a junction to another drive, but didn't do it at all.

Comment: There are no restore points from before the error, because they were disabled before everything happened.

Comment: With "removed" I mean "moved back to where it was before". BTW: It seems that EVERYTHING that was moved during my attempts is running like a charm except the windows settings.

Comment: +1 for Ramhound. I'd back up all your data and programs (there are several questions on SU about this) and then use your system restore disk to revert Windows back to its original state. If you need to move programs away from the C drive consider using "WinDirStat" to find out the ones that use the most space and then `mklink` to create a junction to that specific folder on your D drive - for example my "steamapps" folder is huge so I've moved that (and only that) to the D drive. That's what people with small SSDs tend to do.

Comment: I just want to inform you that I solved the problem. It was a damaged DLL from Internet Explorer (still don't get why that is affecting the explorer from windows.) Reinstalled IE and re registering the dll done the trick (actproxy.dll).

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you dont want you programms on the c:\ drive please do not install them on the c drive and choose during the installation a different drive.

Secondly to move the programm folder like this is no good idea at all. A lot of programms have system files and registry keys stored during the installation. So if you just "move" the files to a different locations a lot of programms wont work. So if you want to change a programm location please consider uninstall the software and reinstall it on a different location.

If you have an old system restore point i would restore the system to that date.

> Every Folder opens in new window when doubleclicked, but not when
>   right-clicked and then "Open"

This can be changed in the folder options.

> Windows started to create restoring points

This can be changed in the system settings.

> Some of my plugins like NetSpeedMonitor disappeared. 
>   Unlocker doesn't appear in context menu anymore.
>   Internet Explorer doesn't start.

This happend because you dont do what you did. Try to reinstall this software.

Comment: OMG and the usual thing just happened that happens to everyone doing something with windows. I am not stupid, and I didn't go full retard like "Well I move everything and then it should work". My Plan was to move C:/Program Files to another drive and create a NTFS junction so I wouldn't have to reinstall it. And of course I know where I could change my system setting IF THEY WOULD BE ACCEPTED BY WINDOWS! I already tried to set everything to where it should be but that just affect the right click standard option and not the double click action for folder opening for example.

Comment: And thanks for making me feel like I shouldn't have asked at all.

Comment: What did you try to accomplish? I didn´t say you were stupid and you didn´t mention any background why you moved it. I´m not sure if that would work ( but it could). A better way to move that folder would have been a linux live cd or attatching the drive to a different computer and then move the files. In both ways im still not sure if it would work cause the file persissions could get messed up. Btw i would recommend a backup software like acronis true image before trying out to take a step where never someone has been :P.

Comment: Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options. There should open up a window with 3 tabs. Please select the second tab (view?) . If you check there the different options you should find one named similar to "Launch folder windows in a separate process", if its active deativate it. If this dosent help try to create a new user and check if the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Most of where Windows is expecting programs and components of programs to be is stored in the registry.  Unless you have deep knowledge of every location in the registry to change, which is impossible as many Windows applications don't document this information, you have "pulled the rug out from under" many of these applications.

Some Windows components, such as the .NET framework and other programs have things in `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared`.  So you have Windows components too that have had the rug pulled out from under them.  You can bet registry entries involved with these programs are not documented.  I'm not sure what these programs do when their expected components are missing, they could make other changes which might be the cause of the effects you are experiencing.

Honestly, backing up your data and reinstalling Windows from scratch is probably going to be the quickest way to get back to a fully functional and reliable system.

If you are running out of drive space, typically you can tell programs during installation to install to an external drive.  You can't run them without the external attached.  To "move" a program, generally you have to uninstall and then reinstall it.

Comment: As I said, I didn't want to just move it, but instead tried to create a NTFS junction for the folders on another drive. I think the part that destroyed everything was using Unlocker while windows was running.

Comment: @th3falc0n I have used Unlocker before. There are no critical system files in Program Files. The two major examples provided are not system files, the loss of the folder might mean you have to reinstall your applications, but thats the worst case.  In the end what you attempted to do is not supported for a reason by Microsoft.  While what you wanted to do is possible, simply stated, you didn't do it the correct way.

Comment: OK so this isn't the real problem at all as all programs that were in C are still running as expected. NetSpeedMonitor and Unlocker are working again after reinstalling them (i think they didn't like to be moved while running ;) ) but the only major problem I NEED to solve is that "explorer opens every double-click in new window". It is especially strange that it only happens with double clicks, but not with right-click "Open"

Answer (score 0):

You should have COPIED your Program Files folder, changed the registry keys, rebooted and deleted the old Program Files folder once everything is up and running.

Junction links are nice but as you can see in this thread : [Can't install Windows 7 service packs with SSD and HDD setup](https://superuser.com/questions/701380/cant-install-windows-7-service-packs-with-ssd-and-hdd-setup/701453#701453) issues can occur (plus as you've seen you need to empty Program Files while Windows is running to make a link... problematic since you're bound to have some files open)

Answer (score -1):

First to comment your comment ;) Calm down. You did not say a word about your plan to make ntfs junction. You just said you wanted to move program files to a different drive, which is really not a good idea. One solution which comes to my mind would be to boot from some other media, like Windows DVD or some other thing which has file manager and try to move the files back. This way the system will not be alive as it was in safe mode and should allow you to move anything anywhere. But I am not sure this will fix the remaining issues... maybe google for specific solutions for these yet if you decide it is worth it.

Another thing you could try is to repair your system using windows installation media if you have one
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

for Ramhound: I would make a comment if I had 50 points :-]

Comment: Most of this answer could have been a comment.  Outside of the comment text, you should link to most of the content from the link, so we don't suffer from dead links in a year

Comment: As I stated in the comment, everything is back where is was.